# How to uninstall vscode theme

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I tried to install a theme and I installed a theme as you can see in the picture, I didn't like that theme, I uninstalled it, but this girl is still there. How to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you sure the girl was installed by the particular theme you are referring. Did you try switching to other theme to see if it solved the issue?

Comment: Name: background
Id: shalldie.background
Description: A simple tool to make your vscode's background look better!
Version: 1.2.1
Publisher: shalldie
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shalldie.background. I installed this (I'm a beginner)